# Form submit called using Link. Need Help

Tags: jquery

I have tried different ways but no success. Googled but can not find this code working.

I want to submit form by clicking Link.  Below is the code. Link Click is called but submit function is bypassing.

```
<a id="Save" class="pageAddLink" href="#" title="Save Page Contents">Save Page</a>
<form action="/Home/Edit" id="first" method="post">
</form>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.pageAddLink").live('click', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        //$("form#first").submit(); //Only this is working fine but below code not
        $("form#first").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("form submit called");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is binding the form-submit logic on click of the link when you should do this outside the click event. From what I can tell, you want the link to actually invoke the `submit` event of the form, not to declare how the `submit` event ought to behave:

```
$("form#theForm").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("Form Submitted"); 
});

$("a").live("click", function(e) { // is there a reason we're using $.live()?
   e.preventDefault();
   $("form#theForm").submit(); // Alerts: Form Submitted
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iqegu4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler....

```
<a id="Save" 
   class="pageAddLink" 
   href="javascript: $('form#first').submit();return false;" 
   title="Save Page Contents">Save Page</a>
```